# Manage a knowledge-base for both a Wiki and a Bot

Tags: markdown, chatbot, wiki

I'd like to create a wiki about a service I'm providing, which the users can browse. I'd also like to provide some kind of chat-bot that helps the user navigate through this wiki with some extra help.

For example, in the morning the bot would ask for certain problems first because they are the ones occurring most at that time. Because I'd like to share this wiki - that I'll call knowledge-base - for both presenting to the user and having it as input for the bot, I don't know what data structure to use. Initially, I'd like to write my wiki in markdown - as it's fairly easy to write by non-technical people too - but it lacks the bit of logic that would make the bot actually useful - fetching contextual information, reaching out to another service, contacting a human because the problem could not be resolved, etc.

This could mean some kind of scripting language that could generate Markdown - sort of like PHP constructing HTML - but that doesn't feel too elegant as it would slowly make the Markdown convoluted with code, reducing readability.

Adding some kind of extra notation seems like an option too - like some kind of navigation, running an external computation, ... - but I'm not aware of such extension.

**TL;DR:** I'd like some kind of wiki descriptor format that can be embedded within the wiki - or just annotate it - that could be both read by the users and used by the bot as a source of information, but with some extra logic or previous knowledge about the user or situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions out there that could interest you since they provide working Wikis based on markdown:

If you don't mind not having online editing capabilities [mdwiki](http://dynalon.github.io/mdwiki) could be a good fit. You'd edit your content with git.
I also used to use the old version of GitBook, but I'm not sure how their new offering compares.

If you need online editing, you could use [w2wiki](https://github.com/panicsteve/w2wiki), but you might want to change the default L&F a bit.

If you need something more powerful, with database support, [wikijs](https://wiki.js.org/) seems like a decent option.

If none of them are what you're looking for, and feel like writing your own, I'm sure you already know about [pandoc](https://www.pandoc.org) for converting to/from MD/HTML which you could use on your server side with your language of choice for your business requirements.